# how to speedup vtkCellPicker

Tags: vtk

Below is a snippet of a molecular viewer written using `vtk/PyQt` which I adapted from a colleague's code. Basically, the viewer is quite efficient regarding the mouse interaction (translation, rotation, zoom). I also need to add a callback which gives me the index of the atom which is picked, this index being transferred in other part of the whole `PyQt` application through signal/slot mechanism. Here the troubles begin. To do so, a `vtkCellPicker` is used but I found that it was painfully slow to retrieve that index (see `on_pick` method). Eventually, it even freezes my application. I tried other pickers which seem to be much much faster (`vtkPropPicker`, `vtkPointPicker`) but being new in `vtk` I do not know how to retrieve the index of the picked atom from those pickers. Would you have any idea how to make it ?

```
import sys

import numpy as np

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

import vtk
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor

vtk.vtkObject.GlobalWarningDisplayOff()

RGB_COLOURS = {}
RGB_COLOURS["selection"] = (0, (1.00, 0.20, 1.00))
RGB_COLOURS["default"] = (1, (1.00, 0.90, 0.90))

CHEMICAL_ELEMENTS = {}
CHEMICAL_ELEMENTS['H'] = {'vdw_radius': 1.09, 'color': '255;255;255'}
CHEMICAL_ELEMENTS['C'] = {'vdw_radius': 1.70, 'color': '0;255;0'}
CHEMICAL_ELEMENTS['N'] = {'vdw_radius': 1.55, 'color': '0;0;255'}
CHEMICAL_ELEMENTS['O'] = {'vdw_radius': 1.52, 'color': '255;0;0'}

NUMBER_OF_ATOMS = 100000

# Hack for reducing objects resolution when the system is big
RESOLUTION = int(np.sqrt(5000000.0 / NUMBER_OF_ATOMS))
RESOLUTION = 10 if RESOLUTION > 10 else RESOLUTION
RESOLUTION = 4 if RESOLUTION < 4 else RESOLUTION


def color_string_to_rgb(color):
    """Convert a color stored in r;g;b format to [r/255.0,g/255.0,b/255.0] format.

    Args:
        color (str): the color to convert
    """

    if not color.strip():
        color = "1;1;1"

    return np.array(color.split(';')).astype(np.float32)/255.


def ndarray_to_vtkarray(colors, scales, n_atoms):
    """Convert the colors and scales NumPy arrays to vtk arrays.

    Args:
        colors (numpy.array): the colors
        scales (numpy.array): the scales
        n_atoms (int): the number of atoms
    """
    # define the colours
    color_scalars = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
    color_scalars.SetNumberOfValues(len(colors))
    for i, c in enumerate(colors):
        color_scalars.SetValue(i, c)
    color_scalars.SetName("colors")

    # some scales
    scales_scalars = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
    scales_scalars.SetNumberOfValues(scales.shape[0])
    for i, r in enumerate(scales):
        scales_scalars.SetValue(i, r)
    scales_scalars.SetName("scales")

    # the original index
    index_scalars = vtk.vtkIntArray()
    index_scalars.SetNumberOfValues(n_atoms)
    for i in range(n_atoms):
        index_scalars.SetValue(i, i)
    index_scalars.SetName("index")

    scalars = vtk.vtkFloatArray()
    scalars.SetNumberOfComponents(3)
    scalars.SetNumberOfTuples(scales_scalars.GetNumberOfTuples())
    scalars.CopyComponent(0, scales_scalars, 0)
    scalars.CopyComponent(1, color_scalars, 0)
    scalars.CopyComponent(2, index_scalars, 0)
    scalars.SetName("scalars")
    return scalars


class MolecularViewer(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    """This class implements a molecular viewer.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent):

        super(MolecularViewer, self).__init__(parent)

        self._iren = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(self)

        self._renderer = vtk.vtkRenderer()

        self._iren.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(self._renderer)

        self._iren.GetRenderWindow().SetPosition((0, 0))

        self._iren.GetInteractorStyle().SetCurrentStyleToTrackballCamera()

        self._iren.Enable()

        self._camera = vtk.vtkCamera()
        self._renderer.SetActiveCamera(self._camera)
        self._camera.SetFocalPoint(0, 0, 0)
        self._camera.SetPosition(0, 0, 20)

        self._previously_picked_atom = None

        self._iren.Initialize()

        self._atoms = np.random.choice(list(CHEMICAL_ELEMENTS.keys()), NUMBER_OF_ATOMS).tolist()

        self._atom_colours, self._lut = self.build_color_transfer_function()

        self._atom_scales = np.array([CHEMICAL_ELEMENTS[at]['vdw_radius'] for at in self._atoms]).astype(np.float32)

        scalars = ndarray_to_vtkarray(self._atom_colours, self._atom_scales, len(self._atoms))

        self._polydata = vtk.vtkPolyData()
        self._polydata.GetPointData().SetScalars(scalars)

        coordinates = np.random.uniform(-100, 100, (NUMBER_OF_ATOMS, 3))

        self.set_coordinates(coordinates)

        self._iren.AddObserver("LeftButtonPressEvent", self.on_pick)

    @property
    def iren(self):
        return self._iren

    @property
    def renderer(self):
        return self._renderer

    def build_color_transfer_function(self):
        """Returns the colors and their associated transfer function
        """

        lut = vtk.vtkColorTransferFunction()

        for (idx, color) in RGB_COLOURS.values():
            lut.AddRGBPoint(idx, *color)

        colours = []
        unic_colours = {}

        color_string_list = [color_string_to_rgb(CHEMICAL_ELEMENTS[at]['color']) for at in self._atoms]

        col_ids = len(RGB_COLOURS)

        for col in color_string_list:
            tup_col = tuple(col)
            if not (tup_col in unic_colours.keys()):
                unic_colours[tup_col] = col_ids
                lut.AddRGBPoint(col_ids, *tup_col)
                colours.append(col_ids)
                col_ids += 1
            else:
                colours.append(unic_colours[tup_col])

        return colours, lut

    def build_scene(self):
        '''
        build a vtkPolyData object for a given frame of the trajectory
        '''

        actor_list = []
        line_actor = None

        line_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        if vtk.vtkVersion.GetVTKMajorVersion() < 6:
            line_mapper.SetInput(self._polydata)
        else:
            line_mapper.SetInputData(self._polydata)

        line_mapper.SetLookupTable(self._lut)
        line_mapper.ScalarVisibilityOn()
        line_mapper.ColorByArrayComponent("scalars", 1)
        line_actor = vtk.vtkLODActor()
        line_actor.GetProperty().SetLineWidth(3)
        line_actor.SetMapper(line_mapper)
        actor_list.append(line_actor)

        sphere = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
        sphere.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)
        sphere.SetRadius(0.2)
        sphere.SetThetaResolution(RESOLUTION)
        sphere.SetPhiResolution(RESOLUTION)
        glyph = vtk.vtkGlyph3D()
        glyph.SetInputData(self._polydata)

        glyph.SetScaleModeToScaleByScalar()
        glyph.SetColorModeToColorByScalar()
        glyph.SetScaleFactor(1)
        glyph.SetSourceConnection(sphere.GetOutputPort())
        glyph.SetIndexModeToScalar()
        sphere_mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
        sphere_mapper.SetLookupTable(self._lut)
        sphere_mapper.SetScalarRange(self._polydata.GetScalarRange())
        sphere_mapper.SetInputConnection(glyph.GetOutputPort())
        sphere_mapper.ScalarVisibilityOn()
        sphere_mapper.ColorByArrayComponent("scalars", 1)
        ball_actor = vtk.vtkLODActor()
        ball_actor.SetMapper(sphere_mapper)
        ball_actor.GetProperty().SetAmbient(0.2)
        ball_actor.GetProperty().SetDiffuse(0.5)
        ball_actor.GetProperty().SetSpecular(0.3)
        ball_actor.SetNumberOfCloudPoints(30000)
        actor_list.append(ball_actor)
        self.glyph = glyph

        self._picking_domain = ball_actor

        assembly = vtk.vtkAssembly()
        for actor in actor_list:
            assembly.AddPart(actor)

        return assembly

    def clear_actors(self):
        """Clear the trajectory and the vtk scene.
        """

        if not hasattr(self, "_actors"):
            return

        self._actors.VisibilityOff()
        self._actors.ReleaseGraphicsResources(self._iren.GetRenderWindow())
        self._renderer.RemoveActor(self._actors)

        del self._actors

    def get_atom_index(self, pid):
        """Return the atom index from the vtk data point index.

        Args:
            pid (int): the data point index
        """

        _, _, idx = self.glyph.GetOutput().GetPointData().GetArray("scalars").GetTuple3(pid)

        return int(idx)

    def on_pick(self, obj, event=None):
        """Event handler when an atom is mouse-picked with the left mouse button
        """

        # Get the picked position and retrieve the index of the atom that was picked from it
        pos = obj.GetEventPosition()

        picker = vtk.vtkCellPicker()
        picker.SetTolerance(0.005)

        picker.AddPickList(self._picking_domain)
        picker.PickFromListOn()
        picker.Pick(pos[0], pos[1], 0, self._renderer)
        pid = picker.GetPointId()
        if pid > 0:
            idx = self.get_atom_index(pid)
            self.on_pick_atom(idx)

    def on_pick_atom(self, picked_atom):
        """Change the color of a selected atom
        """

        # If an atom was previously picked, restore its scale and color
        if self._previously_picked_atom is not None:
            index, scale, color = self._previously_picked_atom
            self._atom_scales[index] = scale
            self._atom_colours[index] = color
            self._polydata.GetPointData().GetArray("scalars").SetTuple3(
                index, self._atom_scales[index], self._atom_colours[index], index)

        # Save the scale and color of the picked atom
        self._previously_picked_atom = (
            picked_atom, self._atom_scales[picked_atom], self._atom_colours[picked_atom])

        # Set its colors with the default value for atom selection and increase its size
        self._atom_colours[picked_atom] = RGB_COLOURS['selection'][0]
        self._atom_scales[picked_atom] *= 2

        self._polydata.GetPointData().GetArray("scalars").SetTuple3(picked_atom, self._atom_scales[picked_atom], self._atom_colours[picked_atom], picked_atom)

        self._polydata.Modified()

        # self._iren.Render()

    def set_coordinates(self, coords):
        '''
        Sets a new configuration

        @param frame: the configuration number
        @type frame: integer
        '''

        self.clear_actors()

        points = vtk.vtkPoints()
        points.SetNumberOfPoints(len(self._atoms))
        for i, (x, y, z) in enumerate(coords):
            points.SetPoint(i, x, y, z)

        self._polydata.SetPoints(points)

        # Update the view.
        self.update_renderer()

    def update_renderer(self):
        '''
        Update the renderer
        '''
        # deleting old frame
        self.clear_actors()

        # creating new polydata
        self._actors = self.build_scene()

        # adding polydata to renderer
        self._renderer.AddActor(self._actors)

        # rendering
        self._iren.Render()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    """This class implements the main window of the application.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)

        self.init_ui()

    def build_layout(self):
        """Build the layout of the main window.
        """

        self._vl = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self._vl.addWidget(self._molecular_viewer.iren)

        self._main_frame.setLayout(self._vl)

    def build_widgets(self):
        """Build the widgets of the main window.
        """

        self._main_frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self)

        self._molecular_viewer = MolecularViewer(self._main_frame)
        self._molecular_viewer.renderer.ResetCamera()
        self._molecular_viewer.iren.Initialize()
        self._molecular_viewer.iren.Start()

        self.setCentralWidget(self._main_frame)

        self.setGeometry(0, 0, 800, 800)

        self.show()

    def init_ui(self):
        """Set the widgets of the main window
        """

        self.build_widgets()
        self.build_layout()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = MainWindow()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I use a different renderer for object picking using an offscreen buffer. See vtkHardwareSelector https://vtk.org/doc/nightly/html/classvtkHardwareSelector.html

Comment: I will have a look. Thx